# What is a render target and how am I creating an Invalid operation?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to create a frameBuffer using a floating point texture and everything has been working fine, the frameBuffer lists as a complete attachment. But now I seem to be getting this error and can not draw into my texture.

```
07-22 21:00:15.180: W/Adreno-ES20(27203): <validate_render_targets:454>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION
```

I have no idea what it means by validate render targets or how it could be an invalid operation. Google does not appear to be my friend either in this matter as I return no results as to what it is. I cant seem to find anything within the opengl sdk docs either.

Heres the code for setting up my framebuffer

```
public void setup(Context context) {
    final float eyeX = 0.0f;
    final float eyeY = 0.0f;
    final float eyeZ = 1.5f;

    final float lookX = 0.0f;
    final float lookY = 0.0f;
    final float lookZ = -5.0f;

    final float upX = 0.0f;
    final float upY = 1.0f;
    final float upZ = 0.0f;

    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, lookX, lookY, lookZ, upX, upY, upZ);

    int vertexShaderHandle = ShaderHelper.compileShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
            ShaderHelper.readShader(context, R.raw.vertex_shader));     
    int fragmentShaderHandle = ShaderHelper.compileShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
            ShaderHelper.readShader(context, R.raw.fragment_shader));

    mProgramHandle = ShaderHelper.createAndLinkProgram(vertexShaderHandle, fragmentShaderHandle, 
            new String[] {"a_Position", "a_TexCoord"});

    vertexShaderHandle = ShaderHelper.compileShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
            ShaderHelper.readShader(context, R.raw.particle_vertex_shader));        
    fragmentShaderHandle = ShaderHelper.compileShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
            ShaderHelper.readShader(context, R.raw.particle_fragment_shader));

    mPartProgramHandle = ShaderHelper.createAndLinkProgram(vertexShaderHandle, fragmentShaderHandle, 
            new String[] {"a_Position"});


    // create the ints for the framebuffer, depth render buffer and texture
    int[] fb, renderTex; // the framebuffer, the renderbuffer and the texture to render
    fb = new int[1];
    renderTex = new int[2];

    // generate
    GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1, fb, 0);
    GLES20.glGenTextures(2, renderTex, 0);

    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTex[0]);

    // parameters - we have to make sure we clamp the textures to the edges
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);

    int GL_OES_texture_half_float = 0x8D61;
    int GL_RGBA32F =  0x8814;
    GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, texW, texH, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, null);
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb[0]);
    GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTex[0], 0);
    //      ShaderHelper.saveTexture(renderTex[0], texW, texH, "test");
    posTex = renderTex[0];
    posFb = fb[0];

    final int buffers[] = new int[2];
    GLES20.glGenBuffers(2, buffers, 0);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[0]);
    GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, spriteBuffer.capacity() * BYTES_PER_FLOAT, spriteBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[1]);
    GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, renderQuad.capacity() * BYTES_PER_FLOAT, renderQuad, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "u_MVPMatrix");
    mTransformsHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "u_Transforms");
    mTexDataHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "u_TexData");
    mTexUniformHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "u_Texture");
    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "a_Position"); 
    mTexCoordHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "a_TexCoord");

    mPosTexHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mPartProgramHandle, "u_Positions");
    mFBPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mPartProgramHandle, "a_Position"); 

    spriteBufferIdx = buffers[0];
    fbQuadBufferIdx = buffers[1];

    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

}
```

and here is the actual draw code

```
 private void renderToTexture() {
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, this.texW, this.texH);

    // Bind the framebuffer
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, posFb);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, fbQuadBufferIdx);
    // check status
    int status = GLES20.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if (status != GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        throw new RuntimeException("FrameBuffer Error; Status = " + status);

    transforms[0] = Fields.screen_width / 2;
    transforms[1] = Fields.screen_height / 2;
    transforms[2] = 0;
    transforms[3] = Fields.screen_height;
    pixels.put(transforms).position(0);
    GLES20.glTexSubImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, pixels);
    GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, pixels);
    Log.d("X", "X=" + pixels.get(0));

    GLES20.glClearColor(.0f, .0f, .0f, 1.0f);
    GLES20.glClear( GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    GLES20.glUseProgram(mPartProgramHandle);

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, posTex);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(mPosTexHandle, 0);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 8, 0);

    // Clear the currently bound buffer (so future OpenGL calls do not use this buffer).
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    // Draw the cubes.
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    //              if (!saved)
    //                  ShaderHelper.saveTexture(posTex, texW, texH, "test2");
    //              saved = true;

    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
}
```

Any idea how I am generating this error or advice for debugging this in the future?

Comment: `GL_RGBA32F` is not a supported texture format in ES 2.0. The fact that you had to define the enum value yourself should give you a strong hint that this is the case. If it were a supported format, it would be part of the API definitions.

Comment: But the error is not thrown until after the draw call. It took that as a valid enum for the function. Also, not all the api definitions are listed. In order for me to access half_float texture format I need to define it manually.